# JUnit testing can't find the method that I want to test

Tags: java, junit

Below is the (incomplete) piece of code containing the method "IntRelation" that I would like to test on whether it throws exceptions or not.

```
public abstract class IntRelation {

    public IntRelation(final int n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Parameter in precondition violated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the (incomplete) piece of code containing the test case for the "IntRelation" method.

```
public abstract class IntRelationTestCases {

    protected IntRelation instance;

    @Test
    public void testException0() {
        Class expected = IllegalArgumentException.class;
        instance.IntRelation(-1);
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that in the second piece of code, NetBeans/JUnit says that it cannot find the method "IntRelation". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's true. It's because you're invoking a constructor like it's a method; don't do that.

I suppose what you wanted to do was `instance = new IntRelation(...);`

or you meant that to actually be a method in which case you haven't defined it properly due to missing a return type.

`public void IntRelation(...)` should do it in that regard.

But then you'd have an issue of an un-instantiated `instance` which should lead you to a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to have some data set up to test it's good practice to use annotations to get things ready for testing.

Example:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Since your class is abstract you can do it like this
    // to get an anonymous class you can test that non-abstract
    // method with...
    instance = new IntRelation() { };
}
```

then call it as usual from the test testing that unit.

```
@Test
public void testException0() {
    ...
    instance.IntRelation(-1);
}
```

I would say, though, naming a method identical to its class name seems potentially confusing. Plus, it's against Java naming conventions to name a method with leading caps; first letter should be lower-case and the rest should camel. For example, `thisIsTheCorrectWay(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that in the second piece of code, I should write this: "protected IntRelation instance = new InRelation(); "?

Comment: I added your code, and now the "IntRelation" in your code is underlined with a red line and says "Implement all abstract methods". If I click on it, I get another error saying "Convert Anonymous to Member"?

Comment: Ah, just noticed it's abstract. Is that really necessary? @Ken. You can't instantiate a interface or abstract class so you'll need to make it not so or provide a concrete implementation.

Comment: Yes, it has to be abstract. How can a concrete implementation be implemented in JUnit? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104581/discussion-between-chieftwopencils-and-ken).